# Replicate 7zip gzip with advanced options in python

Tags: python, gzip, 7zip

I want to compress file with gzip and use python to get result identical to 7zip gzip compressed file, but python gzip does not provide advanced options given by 7zip.

7zip gzip has two options that can be modified: level of compression and word size, 
but python gzip only provides level of compression.

What is the second option word size and how do I specify it from python program?

Comment: You're not going to get binary-identical results from two different encoders, *period*. It's not a remotely realistic thing to request. Even different minor versions of the same engine don't guarantee identical output.

Comment: ...I provided links to the gzip specification (and the deflate specification on which it's built) in your prior question. "word size" is not something that's meaningful in the context of standard-defined gzip; insofar as you have a question about 7zip's proprietary/in-house terminology, the place to go is its authors and their documentation.

Comment: ...so, insofar as the question boils down to "how do I get binary-identical output from the python gzip module and 7zip", said question (which would require a complete rewrite of the python module to no longer be based on zlib) is too broad to be answerable.

Comment: (BTW, I don't generally suggest using gzip in any case where you really care about your data compression; [zstd](https://facebook.github.io/zstd/), depending on how it's tuned, can be faster, better-compressing, or a mixture of both).